# Need to create a trigger that updates without adding same number

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to create a trigger that activates after i make an update in Table A, registering in an audit log the number that i updated in Table A, but if the number has already been added (example the trigger tries to add 1 when there is a 1 already)it must ignore it and only let the first one.

Example:

- Table A updates with 5,5,6,8,4,4
- Then the audit log must save 5,6,8,4

The trigger i have already:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER registro_aeropuerto
AFTER UPDATE ON AEROPUERTO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
A INT;
B INT;
BEGIN 
A := table_A_updated_column_value;
SELECT CASE
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Audit_log WHERE A = Coordinator)
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END INTO B FROM DUAL;
IF B = 0
THEN 
INSERT INTO Audit_log(Coodinator, Date) VALUES (A, trunc(sysdate));
END;
```

Whenever i try to execute the trigger it gives me the next error:

> The symbol ";" has been found when the it was expected:

Comment: Huh?  There is no way this compiles.  Where is table_A_updated_column_value defined? "when the it was expected" what is "it"?  What line is the error on?

Comment: table_A_updated_column is the column that i modified in table A and need to add to the audit log, and whenever i ask oracle to show me the error it leads me to a different row from the page

Comment: Please, provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with actual tables/values that cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

Sample tables (`upd_col_value` is column you're updating; you named it "`table_A_updated_column_value`")

```
SQL> create table aeropuerto (upd_col_value number);

Table created.

SQL> create table audit_log (coordinator number, datum date);

Table created.
```

Trigger can be simplified; no need to declare any additional variables nor to check *first* and insert *next*; do it in the same `select` statement:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger registro_aeropuerto
  2    after update on aeropuerto
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into audit_log (coordinator, datum)
  6      select :new.upd_col_value, sysdate
  7      from dual
  8      where not exists (select null
  9                        from audit_log a
 10                        where a.coordinator = :new.upd_col_value
 11                       );
 12  end;
 13  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into aeropuerto (upd_col_value) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from audit_log;

no rows selected
```

There's nothing in the log because nothing was updated. So, let's update it:

```
SQL> update aeropuerto set upd_col_value = 5;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from audit_log;

COORDINATOR DATUM
----------- -------------------
          5 15.09.2021 07:14:46

SQL>
```

OK; log now contains a row. Another update:

```
SQL> update aeropuerto set upd_col_value = 6;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from audit_log;

COORDINATOR DATUM
----------- -------------------
          5 15.09.2021 07:14:46
          6 15.09.2021 07:15:37

SQL>
```

Right; two rows, as 5 was updated to 6. What happens if we update 6 back to 5?

```
SQL> update aeropuerto set upd_col_value = 5;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from audit_log;

COORDINATOR DATUM
----------- -------------------
          5 15.09.2021 07:14:46
          6 15.09.2021 07:15:37

SQL>
```

Nothing happened; row with `coordinator = 5` was in the table already so new row wasn't added.